# Web crawler class not working

Tags: python, web, web-crawler

Recently, I began working on constructing a simple web crawler. My initial code that just iterated twice worked perfectly, but when I attempted to turn it into a class with error exception handling, it no longer compiled.

```
import re, urllib
class WebCrawler:
    """A Simple Web Crawler That Is Readily Extensible"""
    def __init__():
        size = 1
    def containsAny(seq, aset):
        for c in seq:
            if c in aset: return True
        return False

    def crawlUrls(url, depth):
        textfile = file('UrlMap.txt', 'wt')
        urlList = [url]
        size = 1
        for i in range(depth):
            for ee in range(size):
                if containsAny(urlList[ee], "http://"):
                    try:
                        webpage = urllib.urlopen(urlList[ee]).read()
                        break
                    except:
                        print "Following URL failed!"
                        print urlList[ee]
                    for ee in re.findall('''href=["'](.[^"']+)["']''',webpage, re.I):
                        print ee
                        urlList.append(ee)
                        size+=1
                        textfile.write(ee+'\n')

myCrawler = WebCrawler

myCrawler.crawlUrls("http://www.wordsmakeworlds.com/", 2)
```

And here is the error code generated.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Noah Huber-Feely/Desktop/Python/WebCrawlerClass", line 33, in <module>
    myCrawler.crawlUrls("http://www.wordsmakeworlds.com/", 2)
TypeError: unbound method crawlUrls() must be called with WebCrawler instance as first argument (got str instance instead)
```

Comment: That should be `myCrawler = WebCrawler()` - note parentheses.

Comment: When I did that it returned this error.

Comment: TypeError: __init__() takes no arguments (1 given)

Comment: Yes, you need to specify the `self` parameter to `__init__` (and every other method). Also, what's the point of locally assigning `size` in `__init__`? I strongly suggest that you follow a tutorial (e.g. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html); you can't just guess and hope for the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues. One is one this line:

```
myCrawler = WebCrawler
```

You are not creating an instance of `WebCrawler`, you are just binding the name `myCrawler` to `WebCrawler` (basically, creating an alias for the class). You should do this instead:

```
myCrawler = WebCrawler()
```

Then, on this line:

```
def crawlUrls(url, depth):
```

Python instance methods take the receiver as the first argument to the method. It is generally called `self`, but technically you can call it whatever you want. So you should change the method signature to:

```
def crawlUrls(self, url, depth):
```

(You also need to do this for the other methods you defined.)

Comment: When I do this, it still returns an error, which then stops when I use the containsAny() function by stating self.containsAny(). However, the program then simply executes and then shortly stops without printing anything to the screen.

Comment: I am still seeking an answer to this question, so if you can discover the error, it would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @NoahHuber-Feely: You need to post a stack trace of what happens.

Comment: The solution to this problem was literally right in front of everyone's eyes. I needed to remove the break statement from the try statement.